# Opening hours table

Tags: html

I am trying to make a basic opening hours table in html like this example:

[image: what i am looking for]

I am struggling to add the afternoon hours just bellow the morning hours. What would be the most efficient way to build this?

My code:

```
        <table>
            <tr><th>Sunday</th><td>Closed</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Monday</th><td>9am - 2pm</td><td>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Tuesday</th><td>9am - 2pm</td><td>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Wednesday</th><td>9am - 2pm</td><td>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Thursday</th><td>9am - 2pm</td><td>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: A simple line break `<br>` would seem sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by adding a line break, which it's tag in HTML is `<br>`. It would look like this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Sunday</th><td>Closed</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Monday</th><td>9am - 2pm<br>pm - 7pm</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Tuesday</th><td>9am - 2pm<br>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Wednesday</th><td>9am - 2pm<br>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Thursday</th><td>9am - 2pm<br>3pm - 7pm</td></tr>
</table>
```

I hope it helps! I added some simple CSS to show the borders.